# Timers in C#, how to control whats being sent to the timer1_tick

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, timer

In this following function, that gets executed whenever I do

```
timer1.Enabled  = true

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//code here
}
```

How can I control what gets send to the `(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

I want to use its parameters

Comment: Having "global" class members is probably the best way, explain your final goal here and maybe we'll find better way for what you need.

Comment: I wanted to run an animation of a falling icon, so I wanted to use timer1_tick parameters which I relized I can't. But I have another question which is How come when I do timer1.Enabled = true, it doesn't start right away and other code gets executed and only in the end the code inside timer1_tick gets executred?

Comment: @Alon when posting comment use `@` like I did now to notify otherwise most people won't see your comment. To your question: Timers works in separate thread (asynchronously) so starting a timer won't stop the execution of the parent thread. To have it executed instantly you can simply call it directly: `timer1_Tick(timer1, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I'm building a "4 in a row" game, that has 2 human players. so when a player makes a move, the timer does the animation of the movement, but the problem is when you click twice one after each other, the first animation gets ruined. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @Alon: one way to prevent this is to disable the button (`button1.Enabled = false;`) right after clicking it, then enabling it again (`button1.Enabled = true;`) when the animation is done.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Thx, Btw, I have a matrix of PictureBox, when someone wins, I want to matrix of the PictureBox to be refreshed and all the cells to be empty. Even when i do new PictureBox[int,int], I can still see the old one. what should I do?

Comment: @Alon: it's as simple as `PictureBox[i,j].Image = null;` by assigning its Image to null you effectively clear the picture box control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method signature is fixed, so you can't pass extra parameters to it. However, the `this` reference is valid within the event handler, so you can access instance members of the class (variables declared inside `class` but outside of any method).

Comment: can't I cast object to the object I want ? or cast EventArgs to CellEventArgs?

Comment: @Alon: You can't cast it to a CellEventArgs because it came from a timer control, not some sort of datagrid control.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use Tag property of your timer as userState

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
    MyState state = timer.Tag  as MyState;
    int x = state.Value;
}
```

2) You can use field of reference type to read it in Timer's thread

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = _myState.Value;
}
```

3) You can use System.Threading.Timer to pass state to timer event handler

```
Timer timer = new Timer(Callback, state, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but I relized that you can't know who exactly called that function void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) so I can't use the input parameters (object sender, EventArgs e). I wanted to cast EventArgs to CellEventArgs and get the Cell Details which called that timer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Timer's property in the timer1_tick method, you could do via

```
this.timer1 ex: this.timer1.Enabled =false;
```

or

```
Timer timer = (Timer) sender;
timer.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I wanted to acess the parameters in the timer_tick function. I guess you can't

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make an inheritance from timer class, and there, cast the tick event (from Timer) into a tick_user event or something like this that modify de params and put into EventArgs (this is the right place to do, not in sender) other parameters you want. Also you can make a method with more or less parameters, it's up to you.

Hope this helps.